# Some tweaks to the PHP mailing script

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm designing a website for a charitiy and I came across the problem I'm not able to solve, because I don't have enough knowledge of PHP. I hope someone here would be kind enough to help me out with what I'm trying to achieve...  :)

On the website there is a form for a new members to send their personal data. The form itself works just fine, but I need to make some tweaks, to make it just a bit better.

The HTML fields I'm using on a web template are:

- full name
- date of birth
- house adress
- post adress
- email
- phone
- nickname
- T-shirt size (dropdown menu)
- sticker color (dropdown menu)

Here is the PHP code I have to send the data:

```
    <?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

// configure
$from = 'Demo contact form <info@email.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <info@email.com>';
$subject = '<Data form: ';
$fields = array('name' => 'Full name:', 'birthday' => 'Birthday:', 'house_adress' => 'House adress:', 'post_adress' => 'Post adress:', 'email' => 'Email:', 'phone' => 'Phone mumber:', 'nickname' => 'Forums nickname:', 'shirt' => 'T-shirt size:', 'sticker' => 'Sticker color:' ); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Sample success message.';
$errorMessage = 'Sample error message. Try again later.';
$recaptchaSecret = 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception, 
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key in the config above 
        // from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }


        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Here is what I would like to achieve:

---

In the line

```
    $from = 'Demo contact form <info@email.com>';
```

I would like to get the sender email displayed which should be taken from the email form field.

---

In the line

```
    $subject = 'Data Form: ';
```

I would like to get the sender's full name displayed which should be taken from full name form field.

---

In the line

```
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";
```

I would like to have all the data displayed, but I would like to add them some basic HTML styling so they are not sent as a plain text.

---

If possible, I would also like to get the sender's IP included at the end of the message.

---

Is anyone here kind enough, to help me get things done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use or build up the variables from the POST array? Like `$subject = 'Data Form: ' . $_POST['name'];` or create your variables for later use like `$full_name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name']  : '';` then later you can use `$subject = 'Data Form: ' . $full_name;`

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    // require ReCaptcha class
    require('recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

    // configure
    $from = '';
    $sendTo = 'Demo contact form <info@email.com>';
    $subject = '';


    /*
        array variable name => Text to appear in the email
    */
    $fields = array(
        'name'          => 'Full name:',
        'birthday'      => 'Birthday:',
        'house_adress'  => 'House adress:',
        'post_adress'   => 'Post adress:',
        'email'         => 'Email:',
        'phone'         => 'Phone mumber:',
        'nickname'      => 'Forums nickname:',
        'shirt'         => 'T-shirt size:',
        'sticker'       => 'Sticker color:'
    );

    $okMessage = 'Sample success message.';
    $errorMessage = 'Sample error message. Try again later.';
    $recaptchaSecret = 'xxx-xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx';



    // let's do the sending
    try {
        if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
            /*
                validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception, 
                i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block
            */
            if ( !isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
                throw new Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
            }

            /*
                do not forget to enter your secret key in the config above
                from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
            */
            $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost() );

            /*
                we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address
            */
            $response = $recaptcha->verify( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );


            if( !$response->isSuccess() ) {
                throw new Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
            }

            /*
                everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually
            */
            $message=array();
            $message[]='<html>';
            $message[]='<head><title>New Message</title></head>';
            $message[]='<body>';
            $message[]='<h1>You have new message from contact form</h1>';

            foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
                if( isset( $fields[ $key ] ) ) {
                    $message[]=$fields[ $key ] .':'. $value;
                }
            }

            $message[]='IP:'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $message[]='</body>';


            $from = 'Demo contact form <'.$_POST['email'].'>';
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
                'From: ' . $from,
                'Reply-To: ' . $from,
                'Return-Path: ' . $from,
            );


            $subject='Data form: '.$_POST[ 'name' ];

            $status = @mail( $sendTo, $subject, implode( "\r\n", $message ), implode( PHP_EOL, $headers ) );

            $response = array(
                'type'      =>  'success',
                'message'   =>  $okMessage,
                'status'    =>  $status ? 'Message sent' : 'Message Failed'
            );
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $response = array( 'type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage );
    }

    if ( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
        $encoded = json_encode( $response );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        exit( $encoded );
    } else {
        echo $response['message'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: This one loks fine, thank you! 

Just one more thing - can each given data in the message also get some styling? Something like that:

`code`<p style="background-color: #ddd; padding: 8px;"><strong>full name:</strong></p>`code`

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. Additionally, please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! See: **[Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)** Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.